# Python: if elif loop

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to do a sentiment analysis with twitter data.
I know that the tokens in my POStagged_tweets_lines.json file are 90% neutral.
My loop:

```
with open('POStagged_tweets_lines.json', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    blob = TextBlob(line, classifier=classifier)
```

`#blob = TextBlob('POStagged_tweets.json', 
        classification = blob.classify()
        #print(classification)`

```
pos = "pos"
neg = "neg"
neu = "neu"
negative = 0
positive = 0
neutral = 0

if classification == neu:
    neutral += 1
elif classification == pos:
    positive += 1
elif classification == neg:
    negative += 1
```

`print(negative, positive, neutral)`

Should be counting the sentiments of the tweets in the json file. So, at the end I should be getting an output such as  `5, 12, 100`; but Instead I am getting `0 0 1` and I don't even know where is it coming from.

Comment: 1) We need a [mcve]. Your code throws syntax and other errors. We can't debug that. 2) Don't compare strings with `is`.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot; What should be used instead for strings?

Comment: 64-69 lines must be at the outside of loop.

Comment: **there is no loop** - if staements are conditios. loops typically use `while` or `for`

Comment: @set0gut1 I've tried this, it didn't work. I still get `0 0 1` as output